# Get iframe by id

Tags: jquery, iframe

I'm a little confused with the following code :

HTML :

```
<div class="playerContainer">
    <iframe id="playerFrame" name="playerFrame" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<div class="playerContainer">
```

Javascript :

```
var playerFrame1 = $("#playerFrame");
var playerFrame2 = window.frames["playerFrame"];
alert(playerFrame1); // returns [object object]
alert(playerFrame2); // returns [object Window]
```

My first question is why we get 2 different outputs.

When I try to embed a webpage using playerFrame1 as ID, nothing happens. But everything work fine with playerFrame2. Anybody knows why ?

Thank you.

PS : I have also tried

```
$('playerFrame'), $(iframe[name="playerFrame"]), document.getElementById("playerFrame")
```

No change.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a jQuery question (I'm assuming that $ is the jQuery object).

jQuery returns an array of objects - where window.frames is a mapping to Window objects.

Comment: How do I get the same result using the jQuery object ?

Comment: @user1671731

You need to access the "contentWindow" attribute of the iframe node - but there are some cross-browser issues, so you need to do something like:

`var iframe = $('#playerframe')[0];
var wnd = iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument;`

.. and wnd will be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The first one isn't a DOM object but a [jQuery one](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/). It gives you access to the DOM object (or a collection of DOM objects), and methods to read or modify its state, but also doesn't offer all the methods of the DOM object(s).

This is usually called a jQuery wrapped object.

If you need to get the DOM object from a jQuery one, you may use

```
var obj = $obj.get(0);
```